# Recommended Magento PHP memory limit

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

Simple question. What is your recommended PHP memory limit for Magento?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recommended PHP memory limit for Magento is 512M

From [System Requirements Prior to EE 1.14.1 and CE 1.9.1](https://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements):

> [...]
>
> - PHP Compatibility:
>
>   - PHP 5.4 is supported natively by EE 1.14 and later and by CE 1.9 and later
>   - Earlier CE and EE versions support 5.2.13 - 5.3.24; or 5.4.x with a patch for CE or EE (the patch is listed as PHP 5.4 Compatibility in the EE support portal)
>   - Required extensions:
>
>     - PDO_MySQL
>     - simplexml
>     - mcrypt
>     - hash
>     - GD
>     - DOM
>     - iconv
>     - curl
>     - SOAP (if Webservices API is to be used)
>   - Safe_mode off
>   - **Memory_limit no less than 256Mb (preferably 512)** [bold added]
>
> [...]

For [above these versions](https://magento.com/resources/system-requirements) no memory is specified for system requirements only the PHP versions (PHP 5.4 and 5.5), but there are known issues with the default PHP memory limit of 128 Mb for these PHP versions.

Comment: any references?

Comment: http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements

Comment: 256M died and was buried with version 1.6, time to move on. Last thing you want is a hiccup in the back end caused by exceeding memory limits during a crucial operation. People tend to forget when they spec out a service plan, that the OS, web server, mysql and the php interpreter all need memory to live in, before you even begin to run Magento.

Answer (score 4):

I always give my Magento Projects 1024M of memory and up the [*max_execution_time* setting](http://php.net/max_execution_time) in the PHP file as well.

This recommendation is based on personal experience with file uploads timing out due to PHP having a default **max_execution_time** of 30 seconds, which in theory should be fine 99% of the time, but sometimes it just isn't enough.

Comment: I do pretty much the same

Comment: what value do you use for max_execution_time?

Comment: I have used anywhere from 120 seconds to 300 seconds.  However if something is taking 5 minutes to complete then there are probably other issues that should be addressed.

Comment: Vallier, can you expand on what process you wait 5 minutes to complete for? Any front end visitor should have a page load in less than a second, anything more is too slow. If you are importing data in the admin, or other tasks that could take some time, then the time limit really depends on the amount of processing required. So not sure where the 5 minutes comes from.