# Catalog Price rule not applied

Tags: magento-enterprise, discount, catalog-price-rules

I am using Magento EE 1.14.2, In that Admin panel, created a Catalog price rule and saved. Then I clicked the save and Apply button to apply the price rule for the products.

The screen was loading  for 5 minutes, finally it said, "Unable to Apply the rules".

Can anyone let me know , what is the issue and how can we fix it.

Awaiting for your valuable reply.

Comment: Check your var/log directory for error log

Comment: In the error log , no entries added. Thanks rohit for the response

Comment: Is error log enable from admin? System > Configuration ?

Comment: do you mean System log /exception log ? Please confirm

Comment: Yes. I mean to say this

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 1043

Comment: Increase your memory size in php.ini

Comment: Already memory_limit is set to 2048M

Comment: Check your `.htaccess` file. it may be possible that `.htaccess` rewrite your setting

Comment: Yes. It was overwritten in .htaccess, as 256M. generally what is the maximum limit we need to give ?

Comment: Recommended PHP memory limit for Magento is 512M

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this type of error is increase your php `memory_limit`

Recommended PHP memory limit for Magento is 512M

Source : [Recommended Magento PHP memory limit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13050/recommended-magento-php-memory-limit)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks Rohit, Let me check. Once again thanks for your support